# Вылетает "is not a function" при вызове функции

Tags: javascript, type-error

Функция должна складывать свойства объекта obj2 в объект, на котором был осуществлен вызов этой функции (obj), при этом если свойство из obj2 уже существует в obj, то оставить его без изменений. Функция должна вести список "неродных" свойств объекта, добавленных в него функцией mergeLeft.

При вызове функции вылетает ошибка "obj.mergeLeft is not a function".

Заранее большое спасибо!

```
        function mergeLeft(obj) {
          let result = {};
          let mergedProperties = [];
          for (let i = 0, array = [this, obj]; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (let key in array[i]) {
              if (result[key] === undefined) {
                result[key] = array[i][key];
                mergedProperties.push(array[i][key]); 
              } else {
                mergedProperties = mergedProperties.filter((n) => 
                {return n != array[i][key]});
              }
            }
          } result.mergedProperties = mergedProperties;
          return result
        }

        let obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
        let obj2 = {a: 2, d: 4};

        obj.mergeLeft(obj2)
```

Comment: ну всё верно. mergeLeft - это просто функция не привязанная ни к какому объекту

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать чтобы эта функция получала 2 аргумента - исходный объект и объект2. Тогда получаем:

```js
const mergeLeft = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const result = Object.assign({ mergedProperties: [] }, obj1);
  for (let key in obj2) {
    if (obj1[key] === undefined) {
      result.mergedProperties.push({ [key]: obj2[key] });
      result[key] = obj2[key];
    }
  }
  return result;
};

let obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
let obj2 = { a: 2, c: 48, d: 4, e: 10, z: 15 };

console.log(mergeLeft(obj, obj2));
```